# Ionic build on mac not updating to latest code

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I don't get it!

I've been working with Ionic 3 for months now. I've had no trouble with builds. But for some reason now, every time I build I get the same version of code I previously had.

I've update cordova, so I have cordova 8.
I've deleted my ios platform and rebuild
I've done everything I can think of, and still I can't get the code to update through 'ionic cordova run ios' or through resetting versions and rebuilding through XCode.

I see others have run into this and none of their solutions have worked.

Has anyone figured out what's going on???

Comment: Do you mean you keep building your app’s old code? As if you new code is ignored or

Comment: Hi @Sergey Rudenko, yes. Event after deleting the platform and rebuilding from scratch.

Comment: So did you wipe cache on your ios device?

Comment: From safari... yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a big stretch, but I've run into this when using things like [Code Push](https://github.com/Microsoft/code-push).  I'll deploy my latest code to the device, forgetting that after startup Code Push will just go out and grab whatever code I deployed to Code Push last.

Comment: Its not a big stretch. This is very possible & very real scenario. I just spent a few hours on this. I stopped short of re-formatting my machine.

BTW, any idea how to disable ionic-pro?

Comment: No, sorry.  I don't use ionic-pro.  Glad this prevented you from reformatting!

Comment: @AdwayLele I had similar issue and its very annoying. Removing cordova-plugin-ionic solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to run following:

```
cordova clean
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you update your Xcode to a beta version? This happened to me after I had updated to Xcode 10 Beta and I had to revert back to Xcode 9. Check your 'xcode-select' output and reset it to the defaults.